# Viewing specific dates in a time-series of netCDF maps

Tags: netcdf, noaa

I'm working with a netCDF file that contains global Sea Surface Temperature projections from January 2001 to December 2100, at a monthly resolution.  I would like to be able to view an SST map for specific dates, i.e. visualize the SST projections for 2058.  However, all I'm able to get at this point is a final map, which I assume is the last frame, i.e. the December 2100 map.

I don't need monthly resolution, so I averaged each 12 month section into a yearly mean.  One year resolution is what I want.  As I said, I'd like to be able to call up a certain date and visualize the SST projections for that date.  Creating an animation would also be handy.

The ultimate goal is to use these SST predictions to drive habitat predictions for tuna, which will be in another map layer.  Basically, each cell (0.5° x 0.5°) will have a suitability rating for tuna based on SST, and that suitability will change as the SST changes.

I'm only interested in a section of the Mediterranean Sea, so I have set the target plot area to that using a grid.

I am pretty new to this, so I'm sure there is something fundamentally missing in my code.  I'm just not sure how to approach it.  If anyone could give me some pointers, it'd be much appreciated.  Even if it's a totally different approach, using different packages.

Packages used: RNetCDF

```
    grid <- GridTopology(c(-6.5,30), c(0.5,0.5), c(60,32))

NOAAsst <- open.nc("C:/Users/hayde/Desktop/Final Modelling Project/tos_O1.200101-210012.nc")
print.nc(NOAAsst)
dat<-read.nc(NOAAsst)
sst<-dat$tos
lat<-dat$lat
long<-dat$lon
close.nc(NOAAsst)

latx  <- rep(lat,length(long))
longx <- rep(long, length(lat))
longx <- as.vector(t(matrix(longx,nrow=length(long))))
sst <- data.frame(var  = as.vector(t(apply(sst,c(1,2),"mean"))))
map <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(cbind(longx,latx), sst, proj4string = CRS("+proj=merc +datum=WGS84"))

############  Plotting the image  ###############

sst <- data.frame(temperature = rep(NA,length(coordinates(grid)[,1])))
grid <- SpatialGridDataFrame(grid, sst, proj4string = CRS("+proj=merc +datum=WGS84"))
GridPoints<- coordinates(grid)
MapPoints <- coordinates(map)
for(i in 1:dim(GridPoints)[1]) {
  distance <- spDistsN1(MapPoints, GridPoints[i,], longlat = TRUE)
  grid$temperature[i] <- map$var[which.min(distance)]
}
spplot(grid, scales=list(draw=T))
```

Comment: I would recommend using the `raster` package. It can read, write, and plot `netcdf` without so many steps.

Answer (score 0):

I would handle the subsetting with CDO and then use the package ncview to explore the data.

For example you can extract a subarea such as the Med with

```
cdo sellonlatbox,lon1,lon2,lat1,lat2 tos_O1.200101-210012.nc outfile.nc
```

and then view it with

```
ncview outfile.nc
```

You can animate the images with the arrows at the top of the window.

If you only want a particular year, then you can do that using the cdo seldate function, assuming your dates are defined correctly, or also you can select timesteps.

```
cdo seldate,DATE in.nc out.nc
```

ncview is not publication quality, but it allows you to efficiently explore the data...